# boost BGL Bundled Properties и алгоритм поиска пути.

Tags: boost-bgl, boost, c++

Создаю граф, в котором хочется использовать Bundled Properties, то 
есть чтобы вершины и рёбра можно было описывать структурой.

Но не понимаю как осуществить поиск пути dijkstra_shortest_paths()
C bgl не работал.

Пример прямо отсюда из документации:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html

```
#ifndef BOOST_GRAPH_TRAITS_HPP
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#endif

struct City
{
  string name;
  int population;
  vector<int> zipcodes;
};

struct Highway
{
  string name;
  double miles;
  int speed_limit;
  int lanes;
  bool divided;
};

struct Country {
  string name;
  bool use_right;   // Drive on the left or right
  bool use_metric;  // mph or km/h
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, City, Highway , Country> Map;

int main()
{
std::system("chcp 1251");

Map map; // load the map
Map::vertex_descriptor v = *vertices(map).first;
map[v].name = "Troy";
map[v].population = 49170;
map[v].zipcodes.push_back(12180);
Map::edge_descriptor e = *out_edges(v, map).first;
map[e].name = "I-87";
map[e].miles = 10.;
map[e].speed_limit = 65;
map[e].lanes = 4;
map[e].divided = true;

vector<double> distances(num_vertices(map));
dijkstra_shortest_paths(map, v,
      weight_map(get(&Highway::miles, map))
      .distance_map(make_iterator_property_map(distances.begin(),
                                               get(v, map))));
}
```

1)  weight_map(get(&Highway::miles, map)) - ?
Здесь как я понимаю, происходит создание карты весов рёбер на основе члена miles структуры Highway?

2) Где задаётся вторая вершина "куда"?

Ошибки:

```
C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp(2540): error C2039: type: не является членом "boost::property_value<PropertyList,Tag>"
1>          with
1>          [
1>              PropertyList=City,
1>              Tag=unsigned __int64
1>          ]
1>          C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp(2594): см. ссылку на создание экземпляров класса шаблон при компиляции "boost::vec_adj_list_any_vertex_pa::bind_<Tag,Graph,Property>"
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Tag=unsigned __int64,
1>              Graph=boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS,boost::vecS,boost::bidirectionalS,City,Highway,Country>,
1>              Property=City
1>          ]
1>          C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp(2718): см. ссылку на создание экземпляров класса шаблон при компиляции "boost::detail::vec_adj_list_choose_vertex_pa<Tag,Graph,Property>"
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Tag=unsigned __int64,
1>              Graph=boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS,boost::vecS,boost::bidirectionalS,City,Highway,Country>,
1>              Property=City
1>          ]
1>          C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/graph/properties.hpp(224): см. ссылку на создание экземпляров класса шаблон при компиляции "boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_property_selector::bind_<Graph,Property,Tag>"
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Graph=boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS,boost::vecS,boost::bidirectionalS,City,Highway,Country>,
1>              Property=City,
1>              Tag=unsigned __int64
1>          ]
1>          C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/graph/properties.hpp(233): см. ссылку на создание экземпляров класса шаблон при компиляции "boost::detail::vertex_property_map<Graph,PropertyTag>"
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Graph=boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS,boost::vecS,boost::bidirectionalS,City,Highway,Country>,
1>              PropertyTag=unsigned __int64
1>          ]
1>          главное тестирование.cpp(252): см. ссылку на создание экземпляров класса шаблон при компиляции "boost::property_map<Graph,Property>"
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Graph=boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS,boost::vecS,boost::bidirectionalS,City,Highway,Country>,
1>              Property=unsigned __int64
1>          ]
1>C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp(2545): error C3203: type: неспециализированный класс шаблон нельзя использовать в качестве аргумента шаблон для параметра шаблон "ValueType", требуется действительный тип
1>C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp(2545): error C2955: boost::type: для использования класса шаблон требуется список аргументов шаблон
1>          C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/type.hpp(14): см. объявление "boost::type"
1>          C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/type.hpp(14): см. объявление "boost::type"
1>C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp(2547): error C3203: type: неспециализированный класс шаблон нельзя использовать в качестве аргумента шаблон для параметра шаблон "ValueType", требуется действительный тип
1>C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp(2547): error C2955: boost::type: для использования класса шаблон требуется список аргументов шаблон
1>          C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/type.hpp(14): см. объявление "boost::type"
1>          C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/type.hpp(14): см. объявление "boost::type"
1>главное тестирование.cpp(252): error C2780: boost::iterator_property_map<RAIter,ID,Value,Value&> boost::make_iterator_property_map(RAIter,ID,Value): требует аргументов: 3, имеется: 2
1>          C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/property_map/property_map.hpp(414): см. объявление "boost::make_iterator_property_map"
1>главное тестирование.cpp(252): error C2893: Сбой при специализации функции-шаблона "boost::iterator_property_map<RAIter,ID,std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::value_type,std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::reference> boost::make_iterator_property_map(RAIter,ID)"
1>          Со следующими аргументами шаблона:
1>          'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>
1>          ]
1>          'boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_property_map'
1>главное тестирование.cpp(252): error C2780: void boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(const VertexListGraph &,graph_traits<G>::vertex_descriptor,PredecessorMap,DistanceMap,WeightMap,IndexMap,Compare,Combine,DistInf,DistZero,DijkstraVisitor): требует аргументов: 11, имеется: 3
1>          C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp(395): см. объявление "boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths"
1>главное тестирование.cpp(252): error C2780: void boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(const VertexListGraph &,graph_traits<G>::vertex_descriptor,PredecessorMap,DistanceMap,WeightMap,IndexMap,Compare,Combine,DistInf,DistZero,DijkstraVisitor,ColorMap): требует аргументов: 12, имеется: 3
1>          C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp(366): см. объявление "boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths"
1>главное тестирование.cpp(252): error C2780: void boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(const VertexListGraph &,graph_traits<G>::vertex_descriptor,PredecessorMap,DistanceMap,WeightMap,IndexMap,Compare,Combine,DistInf,DistZero,DijkstraVisitor,const boost::bgl_named_params<T,Tag,Base> &,enable_if_c<(boost::is_base_and_derived<boost::vertex_list_graph_tag,graph_traits<G>::traversal_category>::value,boost::graph::detail::no_parameter>::type): требует аргументов: 13, имеется: 3
1>          C:\включения_C++ 2012\boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp(344): см. объявление "boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths"
1>
1>Сбой построения.
```

Comment: Это ведь не весь код?

Я немного, но активно работал с BGL. Два совета: поставьте boost 1.50(уже вышел, сам не очень давно обновился), и рекомендую, если интересно, почитать книжку по BGL. И попробуйте скомпилировать под MinGW.

Comment: Примерчик посмотрел на MinGW и 1.50 Boost'е. Количество ошибок зашкаливает. Завтра надо будет поаккуратней посмотреть.

Comment: Код тот, что в документации.
Версия 1.52. 

Книгу читаю boost graph library (джереми сик).
Не особо нравится. 
Хотелось бы для начала простые примеры для нахождения кратчайшего пути между графами и минимального остовного дерева. Информации на русском не могу найти.
Обобщенное программирование, выжатое до корки, с С++ и шаблоном посетитель делают чтение этой книги, довольно трудным(как в своё время было с stl).

Где нибудь есть нормальные статьи для того чтобы въехать?

Comment: @manking да, я имел в виду именно эту книжку, она есть на русском("Юпитер") и как раз лежит передо мной в распечатанном варианте. Согласен, что информации на русском почти нет. Я когда-то усиленно смотрел исходники примеров. За красоту порой приходится платить не всегда простым кодом...

Я имел в виду, что у вас хедеры STL не подключены.

Честно говоря, лучше прочитать книжку пару раз, чем статью(лучше пару раз, т.к. стиль изложения мне не очень понравился). Со статьями проблемы..

Comment: придётся читать книгу.

Comment: @manking если вы хотите пользоваться BGL, то придётся.

Comment: Нашел работоспособные примеры здесь:

http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Boost/BGL